# ng-model is not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I am generating html from a api but i am not able to get its values from data binding.
HTML

```
<div class="content-fluid ng-scope" id="angular_template">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="col-md-12">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="frm1.first_name" class="textboxStyle col-md-6 form-control" placeholder="first name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="col-md-12">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="frm1.last_name" class="textboxStyle col-md-6 form-control" placeholder="last name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type="button" ng-click="save(frm1)" value="Submit" />
```

Controller:

```
mod.controller('CreateSimpleFormController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('<url>').success(function(response) {
    var angularTemplate = response;// html string
            document.getElementById("angular_template").innerHTML = angularTemplate;
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    }).finally(function() {}); 

    $scope.save = function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log($scope.frm1.first_name);
    }
});
```

I am getting undefined when i click on submit button. Please help where i am going wrong.

Comment: what exactly is undefined?

Comment: You don't have a form to submit yet you use `type="submit"` in your code. Try with a button with type button and see if it works.

Comment: try to fill both input then press submit

Comment: I have tried with type="button" but the problem remain the same

Answer (score 0):

$scope.frm1 is something you have to define in the controller. If your html output is having any text and you are expecting that to be binded with model variable, that won't happen. Angular evaluates the template, sees it doesn't have variable defined so will make it blank (ignoring the current text value)

Comment: I am new in angular js. I just want the first name and last name values on click of submit button. I have also tried which u have mentioned but it is not giving values.

Comment: Okay then as others pointed out just use  `$scope.frm1 ={};` inside your controller as first line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a dot(.) value, you have to declare it before using it.

```
mod.controller('CreateSimpleFormController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.frm1 ={};
  ...
}
```